# Импортировать картинку в поле image из canvas, Яндекс шаринг

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas

Столкнулась с проблемой, что изображение, получаемое из canvas, не добавляется в поле image. Код следующий (VueJS v.3.5.0):

```
mounted() {
    Script.attach().then(() => {
        window.Ya.share2('share', {
            content: {
                url: 'http://test.ru',
                title: 'test',
                description: 'test',
                image: document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL(),
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Картинки, которые лежат на серваке, добавляются, работает отлично, но что делать в случае с canvas? Может, рисунок нужно сохранить и только потом его вставлять?

Comment: Насколько я помню, там должен быть урл картинки которую скачает сервис в который вы делитесь (например, фейсбук). Очевидно он не может скачать картинку из вашего браузера, так что придётся сохранять на сервер

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо